# 'JedisConnectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-data-redis, jedis

I am trying to use Redis in my spring web project but getting some conflict. I am using the following jar in my pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

but when running the application it throws an error on the console:

```
01:28:21,234 [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] [ERROR] 
Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'exceptionTranslation' defined in com.bison.ams.config.JPAConfig: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jedisConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/bison/ams/config/RedisConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'jedisConnectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:201)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:682)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4762)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5222)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:689)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1888)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:582)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1617)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:265)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:430)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jedisConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/bison/ams/config/RedisConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'jedisConnectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:201)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:534)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:310)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:71)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1565)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'jedisConnectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisStandaloneConfiguration.<init>(RedisStandaloneConfiguration.java:65)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.<init>(JedisConnectionFactory.java:93)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.<init>(JedisConnectionFactory.java:107)
    at com.bison.ams.config.RedisConfig.jedisConnectionFactory(RedisConfig.java:21)
    at com.bison.ams.config.RedisConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$35bb18e.CGLIB$jedisConnectionFactory$0(<generated>)
    at com.bison.ams.config.RedisConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$35bb18e$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6c1a106b.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:318)
    at com.bison.ams.config.RedisConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$35bb18e.jedisConnectionFactory(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 72 more
```

It seems to be a version mismatch but I am not getting any clue which existing libraries have Redis classes. Here is the maven dependency:tree

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] +- com.alibaba:fastjson:jar:1.2.15:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.6.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.8.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j2-impl:jar:2.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jul:jar:2.20.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.2.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.2.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.2.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.dozer:dozer:jar:5.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.2:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15:runtime
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.8:provided
[INFO] +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.0.0.CR1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:jar:0.18.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.2.1.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:jar:8.0.31:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.19.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.modelmapper:modelmapper:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.2-GA:compile
[INFO] +- javax.mail:javax.mail-api:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:31.0.1-jre:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:3.12.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:jar:1.2.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:jar:2.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-keyvalue:jar:2.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:5.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] \- redis.clients:jedis:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO]    \- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.6.2:compile
```

Can someone please point out where the conflict is and how to resolve it? PS: I can't use Spring Boot Starter for Redis as it is a big change for me to move all the existing libraries to match with the parent spring boot starter so want to use individual spring-data-redis and jedis only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mismatching spring dependencies.

You may start with using lower version of spring-data-redis and jedis.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.23.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.2</version> <!-- or 2.9.0 -->
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Exactly. What @sazzad propose is easier way for you. Basically you can see that your dependency https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-redis/2.3.3.RELEASE needs Spring version 5.x but you are using version 4.x (4.2.1 particularly). You can notice that spring-data project is not using same version numbers as Spring itself and it can be confusing. But you can see that 1.8.23 is last Spring 4.x compatible release (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-redis/1.8.23.RELEASE). You should use same version of all Spring Framework deps.

Comment: Getting another problem related to Redis which seems to be still library conflict, if you guys have any idea about it then please have a look this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76847446